# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'W'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I've been trying to get a Shallow neural network using pandas breast cancer and i keep gettin this error, i would greatly appreciate if someone can tell whats actually wrong and how to fix it.

```
File "D:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\una carpeta para los oasda proyectos\Ex_Files_Python_EssT\Exercise Files\basic_hands_on.py", line 55, in predict
    np.array(WT, dtype=np.float32)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'W'
```

I tried to convert the value of W on my dictionary to float32 because i need it to actually procces the equation on the predict function but i keep getting that the type of "W" is a string despite the fact that **print([W])** giving me a matrix.

this is my code for context sake

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

def initialiseNetwork(num_features):
  W = np.zeros((num_features, 1))
  b = 0
  parameters = {"W": W, "b": b}
  return parameters
def sigmoid(z):
  a = 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))
  return a
def forwardPropagation(X, parameters):
  W = parameters["W"]
  b =  parameters["b"]
  Z = np.dot(W.T,X) + b
  A = sigmoid(Z)
  return A

def cost(A, Y, num_samples):
  cost = -1/num_samples *np.sum(Y*np.log(A) + (1-Y)*(np.log(1-A)))
  return cost
def backPropagration(X, Y, A, num_samples):

  dZ = A - Y

  dW = (np.dot(X,dZ.T))/num_samples

  db = np.sum(dZ)/num_samples

  return dW, db
def updateParameters(parameters, dW, db, learning_rate):

  W = parameters["W"] - (learning_rate * dW)

  b = parameters["b"] - (learning_rate * db)

  return {"W": W, "b": b}

def model(X, Y, num_iter, learning_rate):
  num_features = X.shape[0]
  num_samples = (X.shape[1])
  print(num_samples)
  parameters = initialiseNetwork(num_features)
  for i in range(num_iter):
    A = forwardPropagation(X, parameters)
    if(i%100 == 0):
      print("cost after {} iteration: {}".format(i, cost(A, Y, num_samples)))
    dW, db = backPropagration(X, Y, A, num_samples)
    parameters = updateParameters(parameters, dW, db, learning_rate)
  return parameters
def predict(W, b, X):
  WT = np.transpose(["W"])
  np.array(WT, dtype=np.float32)
  np.array(WT,dtype=float)
  Z = np.dot(WT,X) + b
  Y = np.array([1 if y > 0.5 else 0 for y in sigmoid(Z[0])]).reshape(1,len(Z[0]))
  return Y
(X_cancer, y_cancer) = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y = True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_cancer, y_cancer,
                                                   random_state = 25)
def normalize(data):
  col_max = np.max(data, axis = 0)
  col_min = np.min(data, axis = 0)
  return np.divide(data - col_min, col_max - col_min)
X_train_n = normalize(X_train)
X_test_n = normalize(X_test)
X_trainT = X_train_n.T
X_testT = X_test_n.T
y_trainT = y_train.reshape(1, (X_trainT.shape[1]))
y_testT = y_test.reshape(1, (X_testT.shape[1]))
parameters = model(X_trainT, y_trainT, 4000, 0.75)
print(parameters)
print(X_trainT)
yPredTrain = predict(['W'], ['b'], X_trainT)   # pass weigths and bias from parameters dictionary and X_trainT as input to the function
yPredTest = predict(['W'], ['b'], X_testT)  # pass the same parameters but X_testT as input data
accuracy_train = 100 - np.mean(np.abs(yPredTrain - y_trainT)) * 100
accuracy_test = 100 - np.mean(np.abs(yPredTest - y_testT)) * 100
print("train accuracy: {} %".format(accuracy_train))
print("test accuracy: {} %".format(accuracy_test))
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
  text_file.write("train= %f\n" % accuracy_train)
  text_file.write("test= %f" % accuracy_test)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was about to cuss you out for not showing us where the problem was occuring.  But then I happened to match the error message with

```
def predict(W, b, X):
   WT = np.transpose(["W"])
   np.array(WT, dtype=np.float32)
   ...
```

Of course that would produce this error.  An array with character "W" in it certainly can't be turned into an float.

You use `predict(['W']` a number of places, but this isn't one them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where the problem seems to occur:

```
WT = np.transpose(["W"])
np.array(WT, dtype=np.float32)
```

This creates an array with `"W"` in it. Not the variable `W`, but the literal character `"W"`. I think what you meant to type was:

```
WT = np.transpose([W])
```

Likewise, when you call `predict()` I assume you wanted to pass in `parameters["W"]` rather than `"W"`. Remember, `"W"` is just a character, it's not the same as the variable named `W`

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that i wasnt calling the dictionary properly.
i forgot to put like "dictionaryname["W"]".

Answer (score 0):

Your data set has a column which has values 'W'.
You can drop or remove that column  by the following code:

`dataset_name = dataset_name.drop(columns=["column_name"],axis = 1)`

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem at hand though..